# Identity type between A and B being non-empty implies non-emptiness of A and B?

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

In homotopy type theory, if the identity type A=B is non-empty, can we conclude that A and B are also non-empty? If not what constarints can be put on A and B in order that the above statement becomes true for them.

Comment: I voted to migrate, so this can be merged with its cross-posted duplicate.